# facebook share link : the change you wanted was rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, nginx, share

I read stackoverflow since a few year, and this is my first post !!
So here's my problem :
I have a very simple facebook share button that work on an other website with something like that :

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=500,width=700');return false;" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://badhare.barnsonic.com/events/6&amp;t=Christmas%20party%202014" title="Partager sur Facebook" target="_blank">
    <img src="/assets/facebook_icon-f134df030708166ea5ab126a915c0ad1.png" alt="Partager sur Facebook">
</a>
```

When I click on this button the facebook window popup with this message :
"the change you wanted was rejected (422)"
(I tried to post a screen shot, but this is my first post, and I need at least 10 reputation...)

from Wikipedia 422 means :

> 422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918) The request was
>   well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors

What kind of semantic error would it be?
I don't understand the meaning of "the change you wanted was rejected"
Is it a server configuration issue ? a development bug ?

I don't see any error in my app logs, nor in my server logs. Facebook don't even seems trying to access the webpage I want to share
This a Rails 4 website with an nginx server

You can see the webpage [here](http://badhare.barnsonic.com/events/6) 
And a working "share on facebook" on another webpage [here](http://barnsonic.com/photos/47)

That would be great if someone succeed in telling me which difference make the second link works whereas the first link fails !!!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's solved.
I discovered the object debugger from Facebook that helped me to understand what happened :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
In my case, that was just a broken link in the target page....
Cheers !